# Hosting a lavalink server and connecting to it at the same time fails

Tags: python, networking, pi-4, java

I am running a discord bot that requires voice commands in my Raspberry Pi 4, and installed OpenJDK 17.0.1 on it. I also used pyenv to install python 3.10 on the Pi, and set the version to be global. I've installed `lavalink.jar` as well. Lavalink runs fine, it's that the python script, which uses wavelink, cannot connect to the lavalink server. I have also installed `ufw` and ran `sudo ufw allow <my port number>`, yet it still does not work. How can I fix this?

Here is my `application.yml` file

```
plugins:
  lavasrc:
    providers: # Custom providers for track loading. This is the default
      # - "dzisrc:%ISRC%" # Deezer ISRC provider
      # - "dzsearch:%QUERY%" # Deezer search provider
      - "ytsearch:\"%ISRC%\"" # Will be ignored if track does not have an ISRC. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Recording_Code
      - "ytsearch:%QUERY%" # Will be used if track has no ISRC or no track could be found for the ISRC
      #  you can add multiple other fallback sources here
    sources:
      spotify: true # Enable Spotify source
      applemusic: false # Enable Apple Music source
      deezer: false # Enable Deezer source
      yandexmusic: false # Enable Yandex Music source
      flowerytts: false # Enable Flowery TTs source
      youtube: true # Enable YouTube search source (https://github.com/topi314/LavaSearch)
    spotify:
      clientId: "REDACTED"
      clientSecret: "REDACTED"
      countryCode: "US" # the country code you want to use for filtering the artists top tracks. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2
      playlistLoadLimit: 3 # The number of pages at 100 tracks each
      albumLoadLimit: 2 # The number of pages at 50 tracks each
    applemusic:
      countryCode: "US" # the country code you want to use for filtering the artists top tracks and language. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2
      mediaAPIToken: "..." # apple music api token
      playlistLoadLimit: 6 # The number of pages at 300 tracks each
      albumLoadLimit: 6 # The number of pages at 300 tracks each
    deezer:
      masterDecryptionKey: "your master decryption key" # the master key used for decrypting the deezer tracks. (yes this is not here you need to get it from somewhere else)
    yandexmusic:
      accessToken: "your access token" # the token used for accessing the yandex music api. See https://github.com/TopiSenpai/LavaSrc#yandex-music
    flowerytts:
      voice: "default voice" # (case-sensitive) get default voice here https://flowery.pw/docs/flowery/tts-voices-v-1-tts-voices-get
      translate: false # whether to translate the text to the native language of voice
      silence: 0 # the silence parameter is in milliseconds. Range is 0 to 10000. The default is 0.
      speed: 1.0 # the speed parameter is a float between 0.5 and 10. The default is 1.0. (0.5 is half speed, 2.0 is double speed, etc.)
      audioFormat: "mp3" # supported formats are: mp3, ogg_opus, ogg_vorbis, aac, wav, and flac. Default format is mp3


server: # REST and WS server
  port: 14999
  address: "localhost"
  http2:
    disabled: false # Whether to enable HTTP/2 support

lavalink:
  plugins:
  - dependency: "com.github.topi314.lavasrc:lavasrc-plugin:4.0.1"
    repository: "https://maven.lavalink.dev/releases" # this is optional for lavalink v4.0.0-beta.5 or greater
    snapshot: false # set to true if you want to use snapshot builds (see below)
  #    - dependency: "com.github.example:example-plugin:1.0.0" # required, the coordinates of your plugin
  #      repository: "https://maven.example.com/releases" # optional, defaults to the Lavalink releases repository by default
  #      snapshot: false # optional, defaults to false, used to tell Lavalink to use the snapshot repository instead of the release repository
  #  pluginsDir: "./plugins" # optional, defaults to "./plugins"
  #  defaultPluginRepository: "https://maven.lavalink.dev/releases" # optional, defaults to the Lavalink release repository
  #  defaultPluginSnapshotRepository: "https://maven.lavalink.dev/snapshots" # optional, defaults to the Lavalink snapshot repository
  server:
    password: "REDACTED"
    sources:
      youtube: true
      bandcamp: true
      soundcloud: true
      twitch: false
      vimeo: false
      http: false
      local: false
    filters: # All filters are enabled by default
      volume: true
      equalizer: true
      karaoke: true
      timescale: true
      tremolo: true
      vibrato: true
      distortion: true
      rotation: true
      channelMix: true
      lowPass: true
    bufferDurationMs: 400 # The duration of the NAS buffer. Higher values fare better against longer GC pauses. Duration <= 0 to disable JDA-NAS. Minimum of 40ms, lower values may introduce pauses.
    frameBufferDurationMs: 5000 # How many milliseconds of audio to keep buffered
    opusEncodingQuality: 10 # Opus encoder quality. Valid values range from 0 to 10, where 10 is best quality but is the most expensive on the CPU.
    resamplingQuality: LOW # Quality of resampling operations. Valid values are LOW, MEDIUM and HIGH, where HIGH uses the most CPU.
    trackStuckThresholdMs: 10000 # The threshold for how long a track can be stuck. A track is stuck if does not return any audio data.
    useSeekGhosting: true # Seek ghosting is the effect where whilst a seek is in progress, the audio buffer is read from until empty, or until seek is ready.
    youtubePlaylistLoadLimit: 6 # Number of pages at 100 each
    playerUpdateInterval: 5 # How frequently to send player updates to clients, in seconds
    youtubeSearchEnabled: true
    soundcloudSearchEnabled: true
    gc-warnings: true
      #ratelimit:
      #ipBlocks: ["1.0.0.0/8", "..."] # list of ip blocks
      #excludedIps: ["...", "..."] # ips which should be explicit excluded from usage by lavalink
      #strategy: "RotateOnBan" # RotateOnBan | LoadBalance | NanoSwitch | RotatingNanoSwitch
      #searchTriggersFail: true # Whether a search 429 should trigger marking the ip as failing
      #retryLimit: -1 # -1 = use default lavaplayer value | 0 = infinity | >0 = retry will happen this numbers times
      #youtubeConfig: # Required for avoiding all age restrictions by YouTube, some restricted videos still can be played without.
      #email: "" # Email of Google account
      #password: "" # Password of Google account
      #httpConfig: # Useful for blocking bad-actors from ip-grabbing your music node and attacking it, this way only the http proxy will be attacked
      #proxyHost: "localhost" # Hostname of the proxy, (ip or domain)
      #proxyPort: 3128 # Proxy port, 3128 is the default for squidProxy
      #proxyUser: "" # Optional user for basic authentication fields, leave blank if you don't use basic auth
    #proxyPassword: "" # Password for basic authentication

metrics:
  prometheus:
    enabled: false
    endpoint: /metrics

sentry:
  dsn: ""
  environment: ""
#  tags:
#    some_key: some_value
#    another_key: another_value

logging:
  file:
    path: ./logs/

  level:
    root: INFO
    lavalink: DEBUG
    lavalink.server.io.SocketContext: TRACE

  request:
    enabled: true
    includeClientInfo: true
    includeHeaders: false
    includeQueryString: true
    includePayload: true
    maxPayloadLength: 10000


  logback:
    rollingpolicy:
      max-file-size: 1GB
      max-history: 30
```

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

After some digging, I have used the `netstat -t -l -n` command and got this result:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

This was run while the lavalink server was running. I presume that this means that the lavalink server is not recognized by the Raspberry Pi, so how would I make my Pi recognize the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking around, I have found the answer to my problem.

I wasn't calling Lavalink from its directory (instead calling it from somewhere else), causing it to default to port 8080 (as seen in the `netstat -t -l -n` command), and use a different password than the one I set in the `application.yml` file, causing it to be unreachable by my python program.